# Using gcc not llvm-gcc with Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, gcc, osx-lion, llvm

`gcc` is symbolically linked to `llvm-gcc` on Mac OS X Lion.

```
prosseek ~> ls -alF /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Nov 12 14:39 /usr/bin/gcc@ -> llvm-gcc-4.2
```

How can I setup to use `gcc-4.2` when `gcc` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a way to use gcc with Xcode 4.2 - http://caiustheory.com/install-gcc-421-apple-build-56663-with-xcode-42

Answer (score 13):

As of Xcode 4.2 in Lion, Apple no longer ships its previous version of `gcc-4.2`, which was in Xcode 4.1 and earlier versions.  It now only ships `llvm-gcc` (gcc front-end with `llvm` code backend) and `clang` (clang front-end with `llvm` backend).  While it is possible to install legacy versions of *vanilla* GNU gcc-4.2 from other sources, like MacPorts, (and without disturbing `/usr/bin`), Apple has made it clear that they aren't going to be supporting `gcc` anymore and that they want developers and users to move to `clang`.

Comment: Ned is correct.  It's probably possible to compile gcc yourself from source, but unless you absolutely have to have gcc, you're better off going with llvm-gcc since your code will be forward compatible and given the amount of energy being devoted to llvm, it's likely going to be a much better compiler (and likely already is).

Comment: On my Mac OS X Lion, I still have gcc-4.2, together with llvm-gcc-4.2. I guess this was misleading to make me think there are two gcc compilers.

Comment: Have you installed the current Xcode 4.2.x?  If you start from there, there is no `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`.  Xcode 4.1 for Lion and earlier releases did have `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`.

Comment: @Ned : I installed Xcode 4.0, and then updated to have Xcode 4.2.

Comment: The point is that Apple no longer supports non-LLVM gcc-4.2 with the most recent Xcode for Lion.  So the answer to your original question is that there is no way to do it "officially" since gcc-4.2 doesn't exist anymore.  Clearly there are ways to keep an old gcc-4.2 around and use it, i.e. by changing paths etc.  What more of an answer do you need?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced some problems in compiling stuff (condor for instance) with both llvm-gcc and clang os I had to get the original gcc.

I installed the version 4.6 using [homebrew](https://brew.sh) https://raw.github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/master/duplicates/gcc.rb

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/master/duplicates/gcc.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally just use the Apple gcc, llvm or not, to build the latest gcc available.  Even if /usr/bin/gcc were really gcc and not a wrapper over some llvm build, it's still crazy old.  I documented my experience with the build process [here](http://staticimport.blogspot.com/2012/02/building-gcc-462-on-os-x-lion.html).