# Compiling on Snow Leopard: C and C++ compilers are different

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, osx-snow-leopard, autoconf

I am trying to compile Icecat on a 32bit iMac with Snow Leopard.
I've installed the latest versions of Xcode, Tigerbrew, Yasm, Python 2.7, Python 3.5, and PIP (and I'm using Autoconf2.13).

I'm able to get up to the configure part, and then when I run this:

```
../configure --with-l10n-base=../l10n --enable-official-branding
```

I get the following error:

```
configure: error: Your C and C++ compilers are different. You need to use the same compiler.
```

My GCC, G++ versions are both 4.2.1 when I query them with --version

I've scoured the internet for related things but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this.

Here is the link I'm following:

https://libreplanet.org/wiki/Group:IceCat/Compile_and_package/build_52.3.0_on_macOS_10.13_High_Sierra

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: MIght be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707367/using-gcc-not-llvm-gcc-with-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043415/spidermonkey-build-configure-error-configure-error-your-c-and-c-compilers-a

Comment: Update: after reviewing those articles and looking at my own system, I found my c++ link did not point to G++, but rather to C++-4.2 in the same folder. I'm going to try to figure out how to change that symlink and see if that doesn't break everything.

Comment: Update 2: that did not work. I still get the same error. on the upside, it also didn't break anything that I can tell